# inserting text after a specific searchng for a particular text in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to insert/add a line after searching a particular string or text

```
header 1
      text1
      text2

header 2
      text4
      text5
```

Expected output

```
header 1
      text1
      text2
      text3 

header 2
      text4
      text5
```

I have tried with ansible lineinfile, blockinfile, replace,regexp. I was able to add the required text but it is adding at the end of the file as shown below

```
header 1
      text1
      text2


header 2
      text4
      text5

      text3
```

I want it to be added exactly under header1 and after text2

Comment: I am unable to format the above question correctly. So i have uploaded the same at https://github.com/shettypriy/ansible/blob/master/ansible_text

Comment: Please help me on this. Tired all possible ways, but could not get the desired output

Comment: anyone please help me on the code

Answer (score 0):

Below is the task you're looking for

```
- lineinfile:
    path: "/tmp/test.txt"
    insertafter: '^\s*text2\s*$'
    line: '      text3'
```

Before

```
$ cat /tmp/test.txt 
header 1
      text1
      text2

header 2
      text4
      text5
```

After

```
$ cat /tmp/test.txt 
header 1
      text1
      text2
      text3

header 2
      text4
      text5
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below

```
  - name: Test
    lineinfile:
     path: /tmp/file.txt
     line: '      text2\n      text3'
     regexp: '      text2'
     backrefs: yes
```